# In PyCharm, after downloading Python 3, still invalid to use

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.7

Consider:

[image]

My PyCharm installation was running Python 2. I downloaded Python 3.7 and installed it. It's able to work in PyCharm when I first time run it, however, when I reopen the file and try to run it, it shows warning message:

> Invalid Python interpreter selected

And when I try to switch it into 3.7, the choice is shown in red and says invalid.

Comment: This may help you.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Comment: Click the gear icon next to the **Project Interpreter:** dropdown and select **Add...**. Select **Virtualenv Environment** and select either a **New Environment** or **Existing Environment**.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm with Python > 3.3 is using venv (virtual environment) to allow per project Python modules. You need to create a new valid venv (as described in kimbaudi's comment):

> Click the gear icon next to the *Project Interpreter*: dropdown and
>   select Add.... Select Virtualenv Environment and select either a *New
>   Environment* or *Existing Environment*

If you want to use your preinstalled system modules, you need to check *Inherit global site-packages* or otherwise you need to reinstall the modules you want to use in the venv. Also see [configure a virtual environment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html).